# Minecraft Inventory Scanner

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to do a sort of "inventory scanner" that scans EVERY slots of the inventory of a player. I don't want to write 32 commands in 32 commands blocks, so is there a way to make it short?

For more precision, what I need to scan is the TNT blocks, lava buckets, flint & steel, detected either if renamed or not renamed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using

```
/testfor @p {Inventory:[{id:"<block or item>"}]}
```

This will check for a specific item in the inventory, ignoring slots, using only 1 command block per item. Make sure you use the modpack prefix before your items. For vanilla Minecraft items, it is `minecraft:<block or item>`.

Comment: I use correctly the item's name but the command block says: Kimatuy (me) don't have any structure like this

Comment: @Kimatuy Can you post the command here so I can take a look at it?

Comment: I'm sorry, the world in which I putted the command been deleted before you asked; I can only tell you this: `/testfor @p {Inventory:[{id:"tnt"}]}`

Comment: Try using minecraft:tnt instead of just tnt. Your New commando would be: `/testfor @p {Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:tnt"}]}`

Comment: @Kimatuy Could you mark my answer as answer then? Others will be able to see what worked for you easier then ;)

Comment: I think that it is already done... Or I'm wrong?

Comment: @Kimatuy My fault! It seems that it is marked as answer now.

Answer (score -2):

You can do `/testfor @p {Inventory:[{id:"tnt"},{id:"lava_bucket"},{id:"flint_and_steel"}]}`

Comment: this question has already an answer, and yours adds nothing more as it is a case example. you should at least explain what it is doing...